# How to choose a random item from an array and how a debounce for x amount of time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Original Question:**

Here's my problem, I have a list of tokens that I need to use to login to an account, I'm fine with completely randomizing these items but I want to remove a token I used for about 30 seconds because during that time period the account is in use and cannot be used by anyone else. How would I be able to remove the token from the array for a certain period of time and be able to place it back in the array after x amount of time? (30 seconds).

**My solution I thought of:**

I created 2 function, one to retrieve a random token from the array and another to actually carry out the function for removing the token and placing it inside of the array in x amount of time (30 seconds)

My Code:

```js
const tokens = ["Token1", "Token2", "Token3"]; // Tokens

function runToken(index, value) { // Does the work of removing the element from the array and placing it back in the array.
  tokens.splice(index, 1); // Removes the chosen token from the array
  setTimeout(() => { // waits 5 seconds to push the array element back
    tokens.push(value); // Action to push it back
  }, 30000);
}

function getActiveToken() { // Function to use in order to get the item from the array
  let chosenToken = tokens[Math.floor(Math.random() * tokens.length)]; // Chooses a random element avaliable in the array
  let chosenTokenIndex = tokens.indexOf(chosenToken); // Retrieves the index for use later
  runToken(chosenTokenIndex, chosenToken); // Runs the function above to remove the token and push it back later
  return chosenToken; // Returns the token so that you can use it.
}

console.log(getActiveToken());
         //-- "Token1"
```

If you have a more efficient way of doing this I would love to see it!

Comment: If you've found a solution and would like to help other users with the same problem, please pose your question as you were originally going to ask it and present your code that solves the question as an answer to your own question. Congrats on getting it to work.

Comment: By the way, instead of using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to delay the code for an amount of time, consider using `setTimeout` which is exactly the same but only runs once (no need to stop it from looping).

Comment: Rather than removing and adding elements to the array, try swapping the selected token to the end of the array and change the range to choose random index.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing items could become expensive operations as the size of the array grows. So, as an alternative in this scenario, we could use "swap". whenever we randomly choose an item, swap it with the last element and exclude it from the selection range for a specifc amount of time.

```js
const tokens = ["Token1", "Token2", "Token3", "Token4" , "Token5", "Token6" ];      
const delay = 2000; // 2 Seconds

function getToken() {

    if( getToken.limit == undefined ){
        getToken.limit = getToken.limit || tokens.length;
    } else if (getToken.limit == 0) {
        return "No Active token";
    }
    
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()* getToken.limit );    
    var activeToken = tokens[index];

    tokens[index] = tokens[getToken.limit-1];
    tokens[getToken.limit-1] = activeToken;       
    
    getToken.limit --;        
    setTimeout(function() {
        getToken.limit ++;
    },delay);    
    return activeToken;
};

console.log(getToken())
console.log(getToken())
console.log(getToken())
console.log(getToken())
console.log(getToken())
console.log(getToken())
console.log(getToken())
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(getToken());        
},3000);
```